# SAS iteration through table

Tags: loops, sas

I have two tables. The first table contains columns for student: **ID**, **first_name**, **last_name**, **book**. The second table contains columns for book: **title** and **availability**. I need to randomly assign a book title from the second table to each student in the first table. The number of books is limited and specified in the "availability" column.

```
I tried something like:

%let title;
data student_book;
set first_table;
if missing(book) then do;
call execute(proc sql; select title into :title from second_table where availability > 0 order by rand("uniform"); quit;');
book = "&title";

end;
run;

but it's not working, probably, CALL EXECUTE is evaluated late :(
```

Comment: When you randomly assign book titles, do you want each book title that has availability to have the same probability of being selected, or do you want the probably of being selected to be weighted by the number of books available?  If the availability for a title is two, then it's ok for that title to be matched to two different students, right?

Comment: Yes, I want each title to have the same probability of being selected at each selection. The number of certain titles is small and their availability will need to be subtracted at each selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`call execute` happens after the data step. You cannot use the results of `call execute` within a data step. If you want to pull from `second_table`, subtract its availability, then randomly pull a new title from the table where availability > 0, one option is to use a macro loop that iterates and updates both tables.

Sample data:

```
data student_book;
    set sashelp.class;

    select(_N_);
        when(1) book = 'book1';
        when(2) book = 'book2';
        when(3) book = ' ';
        when(4) book = ' ';
        when(5) book = 'book3';
        when(6) book = 'book4';
        when(7) book = ' ';
        when(8) book = ' ';
        otherwise;
    end;

    if(_N_ LE 8);

    keep name book;
run;

data second_table;
    input title$ availability;
    datalines;
book5 1
book6 2
book7 3
book8 4
book9 5
;
run;
```

Code:

```
%macro replace_missing_books;
    
    /* Count missing books */
    %let dsid     = %sysfunc(open(student_book(where=(missing(book)))));
    %let nmissing = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid, nlobsf));
    %let rc       = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

    %do %until(&nmissing = 0);
       
        /* Pull a random book */
        proc sql noprint outobs=1;
            select title
            into :title trimmed
            from second_table
            where availability > 0
            order by rand('uniform')
            ;
        quit;

        /* Update the first instance of a missing book */
        data student_book;
            modify student_book;
            where missing(book);

            book = "&title";
            replace;
            stop;
        run;

        /* Update book availability */
        data second_table;
            modify second_table;
            where title = "&title";
            availability = availability-1;
        run;

        /* Check how many missing books are left */
        %let dsid     = %sysfunc(open(student_book(where=(missing(book)))));
        %let nmissing = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid, nlobsf));
        %let rc       = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
    %end;
%mend;
%replace_missing_books;
```

`student_book`

```
Name    book
Alfred  book1
Alice   book2
Barbara book9
Carol   book9
Henry   book3
James   book4
Jane    book8
Janet   book5
```

`second_table`

```
title   availability
book5   0
book6   2
book7   3
book8   3
book9   3
```

Comment: The count of some titles is very small (in units) so I would need to check their availability in that cycle and subtract 1 from their availability after each selection of a specific title.

Comment: Got it, so you want selection with replacement that updates the number of books available with each selection?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want each book copy that is available to have the same probability of being selected.

You have data with one record per book title, and you know the number of copies of the title that are available:

```
data booksummary ;
  input title $1 availability ;
  cards ;
A 10
B 10
C 5
D 0
;
```

One way to approach this would be to make a new dataset that has one record per book copy available.  So instead of the above four records, you would have 25 records.  And you can create a random number for each record, which you can use to sort the records into a random order:

```
data books (keep=title rand);
  set booksummary ;
  call streaminit(123);
  do i=1 to availability ;
    rand=rand("Uniform");
    output ;
  end ;
run ;

proc sort data=books ;
  by rand ;
run ;
```

Then when you have the available books in random order, you can just smush the column of book titles onto your column of student names.  To 'smush' data you can use the MERGE statement with no BY statement.

```
options mergenoby=nowarn ; *smush coming ;
data want ;
  merge sashelp.class (keep=name in=a)
        books (keep=title)
  ;
  *no by statement, 1:1 smush ;
  if a ;
run ;
options mergenoby=error ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally a suggestion would be to use a `SET` statement with the `POINT=<var>` to select a random title to assign a student.  However, due to the transactional nature, the availability should drop by 1 each time a book is assigned.

Example:

Assign each book available a random number (draw order) and use that in a 1:1 merge to assign to a student.

```
data books;
  call streaminit(20230410);

  do bookid = 1 to 30;
    avail = rand('integer',0,10);
    total + avail;
    output;
  end;

  put 'NOTE: total avail: ' total;
  drop total;
run;

data bookrandom;
  set books;
  do _n_ = 1 to avail;
    draw = rand('uniform');
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=bookrandom;
  by draw;
run;

data students;
  do studentid = 1 to 100;
    output;
  end;
run;

data 
  studentbooks(keep=studentid bookid) 
  bookout(keep=bookid where=(not missing(bookid)))
;
  * 1-1 merge to assign an available book as previously random ordered;
  merge students bookrandom(drop=draw);

  if missing(studentid) then stop;
run;

data books;
  modify books bookout; 
  by bookid;
  avail = avail-1;  
run;

%let syslast=books;
```